# Reference network file in command line with SSH protocol

Tags: ssh, unix, network-filesystem

I'm trying to reference a file in the command line, but I keep getting the 'No such file or directory' error.  The system uses SSH for the protocol.

Examples (that cause error):

```
grep regex <SERVER1:/home/app/log/biglog

grep regex <SERVER1:home/app/log/biglog
```

Comment: ssh is not a network-filesystem, it's a remote shell

Comment: Javier: Not that what you said isn't true, but there is sshfs, which I would call a network filesystem.

Comment: I guess you're trying to use the syntax seen in `rsync` examples.  Generally, 'host:path' referencing is only supported by some applications and NOT the shell. Or maybe you're using the wrong shell that does not supoprt such a feature :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

umm i think you'll have better luck with this:

`ssh <user>@<server> grep regex <path>`